# Mongo error duplicate key not making much sense

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I get this error on updating a record, instance.isNew is set to false before I call save()

```
errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.mycollection index: date_1 dup key: { : new Date(1552176000000) }'
```

If I am updating my does mongo care if a key value is equal to what it was before the save is called?

thanks!

Comment: Makes a lot of sense to me. You have a "unique" index on a field called `date` and you are inserting exactly the same value as an existing document for that field. You cannot do that, and you probably do not need a "unique" index on that field.

Comment: You also largely appear confused here as anything you instantiate with `var instance = new MyModel()` **is new**. The [`isNew`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) is simply a flag, but your `new MyModel()` returns something with a completely separate `_id`. Therefore it's an "insert" and not an "update".

Comment: `date: { type: Date, unique: true, required: true },` indeed you are right. Hazy day. Thanks @NeilLunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provide the error on updating the record we can conclude lots of sense as from the provided comments by @Neil Lunn, Please check the below information from your error:

```
errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.mycollection index: date_1 dup key: { : new Date(1552176000000) }'
```

1. Your database name: ***mydb***
2. Your collection name : ***mycollection***
3. A **unique index** on your collection ***mycollection*** is : ***date*** and it is created as:

   use mydb

   db.mycollection.createIndex({date:1}, {unique:true})
4. Since there is **unique index** on `date` fields you can't put the same object again and again.